# Проблема Bootstrap Tabs, почему вкладки переходят на новую строку и не переключаются обратно?

Tags: bootstrap, frontend, bootstrap4, tabs

Пытался создать вкладки на Bootstrap 4, первая вкладка не перестаёт висеть даже при переключении, остальные вкладки при переключении дальше сдвигаются на одну строку ниже, и к тому же вкладки не переключаются на предидущие... Пытался найти ответ на эти кучку вопросов - не нашел. (Может и плохо искал)

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-DfXdz2htPH0lsSSs5nCTpuj/zy4C+OGpamoFVy38MVBnE+IbbVYUew+OrCXaRkfj" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.1/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-9/reFTGAW83EW2RDu2S0VKaIzap3H66lZH81PoYlFhbGU+6BZp6G7niu735Sk7lN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.0/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-+YQ4JLhjyBLPDQt//I+STsc9iw4uQqACwlvpslubQzn4u2UU2UFM80nGisd026JF" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <script src="menu.js"></script>
    <title>App</title>
</head>
<body>
<!-- .container центрирует блок и устанавливает его ширину в зависимости от контрольных точек разрешения монитора  -->
<div class="container header-block">
    <div class="text"><p class="title">HELLO MY DARKNESS</p></div>
    <nav class="menu">
        <ul>
            <li id="menu1">Suicide
            <ul class="sub-menu">
                <li>submenu</li>
                <li>submenu</li>
                <li>submenu</li>
            </ul>
            </li>
            <li>Outside</li>
            <li>Home</li>
            <li>Gun</li>
            <li>Exit</li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
</div>
<div class="container" id="content-block-1">
    <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
        <li class="nav-item" data-toggle="tab" href="#page1">Main Page</li>
        <li class="nav-item" data-toggle="tab" href="#page2">About Page</li>
        <li class="nav-item" data-toggle="tab" href="#page3">Touba Page</li>
        <li class="nav-item" data-toggle="tab" href="#page4">Niam Page</li>
        <li class="nav-item" data-toggle="tab" href="#page5">Closed Page</li>
    </ul>
</div>
<div class="tab-content container">
        <div class="tab-pane fade show active" id="page1">
            <p>The capybara (Hydrochoerus hydrochaeris) is a giant cavy rodent native to South America.</p>
            <div/>
            <div class="tab-pane fade" id="page2">
                <p>dfhdfgjdfhjdrth<p/>
            </div>
            <div class="tab-pane fade" id="page3">
                <p>3423t523452345234<p/>
            </div>
            <div class="tab-pane fade" id="page4">
                <p>23452345jghjhijhgg23452345<p/>
            </div>
            <div class="tab-pane fade" id="page5">
                <p>1h1h1h1h1h1h1h1hh1h1h1h1h<p/>
            </div>
        </div>
</body>


</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

**ОТВЕТ НАЙДЕН, НЕ ЗАКРЫТЫЙ DIV :)**